# mysql join sum from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

This is my table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65LHJ.png]

I'm trying to make a list of the users with most earnings (TOP List).
I was using **SUM(earnings)** and **GROUP BY username**, but I want to **SUM** the **upline_earnings** too.

In the table above **user1** is upline of **test**, so all earnings from **test** should be counted as **user1** earning.

This is my code:

```
SELECT COUNT (a.id) as total,
             (SUM(CASE WHEN b.upline=a.username THEN b.up_earnings ELSE 0 END)+SUM(a.earnings)) as tot_earnings,
             SUM(a.dls) as tot_dls,
             a.username
FROM logs a left join logs b ON a.username=b.upline
GROUP BY a.username ORDER BY tot_earnings DESC
```

But it isn't working! Looks like the results from table A is going duplicated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mefht.png

Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Images? That's not how we roll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to aggregate the table by `username` before doing the `join`.  If I understand what you are trying to do, this might be the query:

```
SELECT l.username, count(*) as total_uplines,
       coalesce(sum(b.up_earnings), 0) + l.earnings as tot_earnings,
       l.tot_dls
FROM (select l.username, sum(l.earnings) as earnings,
             sum(l.dls) as tot_dls
      from logs l
      group by l.username
     ) l left join
     logs b
     ON l.username = b.upline
GROUP BY l.username, l.earnings, l.tot_dls
ORDER BY tot_earnings DESC;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!! One question, if I had to add a WHERE clause to check if date is today, I must add in both SELECT clause?

Comment: @user3144996 . . . Probably.  If you only want `earnings` and `up_earnings` from today, then you would want to add the filter to both.